# Apache Camel: FTP files with scheduler (close connection when directory is empty)

Tags: java, ftp, apache-camel

I would like to use Apache Camel for sending files from a local directory to a FTP location. We only get 1 or 2 times a day files in that local directory. So it isn’t necessary to have that connection open the whole day. What I would like to achieve is that we will open the connection when there are files in the directory (this is something we could do by checking the dir), but how could we check if sending the files with Apache Camel is done and close the connection?

Is there some feedback from the RouteBuilder or what is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `disconnect=true` option to close the connection after sending is complete.

See the documentation at: http://camel.apache.org/ftp2

Comment: Yes that is something I saw, but when I add a new file to the local directory it will be sent to the FTP location. How does that work, will it reopen the connection automatically?

Comment: Yes it opens the connection if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I solved the issue a little bit different, please see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the issue by using the FTPToClientRouteBuilder which is called in the following method:

```
@Override
public void sentFilesViaFTPToClient() {

    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

    try {
        context.addRoutes(new FTPToClientRouteBuilder());
        context.start();

        while (true) {
            if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(context.getRoutes())) {
                LOG.info("Finished sending files via FTP.");
                context.stop();
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't FTP files", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            context.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //ignore exception
        }
    }
}
```

FTPToClientRouteBuilder

```
public class FTPToClientRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FTPToClientRouteBuilder.class);

private String ftpLocation;
private String uploadLocation = "file:" + location + "?delete=true&moveFailed=../error&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true";

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    // set graceful shutdown timeout
    getContext().getShutdownStrategy().setTimeout(10);

    from(uploadLocation)
        .choice()
            .when(body().isNotNull())
            .log("Uploading file ${file:name}")
            .to(ftpLocation)
            .log("Uploaded file ${file:name} complete.")
        .otherwise()
        .process(new ShutdownProcessor());
}

private class ShutdownProcessor implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    exchange.getContext().stop();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.error("Couldn't stop the route", e);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
}
```